# Displaying roman character on html

Tags: html, character-encoding, character

How to write the following roman letter in html  with out using unicode

```
Φ
Ω
ω
```

i just pasted it like below

```
<body>
 Φ : phi
 Ω : ohm
 ω :omega
</body>
```

but it is not rendering

Comment: These are Greek letters, not roman. More importantly, they work just fine in HTML, provided that the character encoding is properly declared. The question now contains no hint of what has been done in order to declare the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Entities and/or ISO Latin-1 codes can be placed in source code like any other alphanumeric characters to produce special characters and symbols that cannot be generated in HTML with normal keyboard commands.

```
Phi     &Phi;       Φ
phi     &phi;       φ
Chi     &Chi;       Χ
chi     &chi;       χ
Psi     &Psi;       Ψ
psi     &psi;       ψ
Omega   &Omega;     Ω
omega   &omega;     ω
```

source : http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php